# How do I make the 'order by' clause in an Oracle function use a variable representing a numeric index?

Tags: oracle

I'm emulating the [DESCRIBE *tablename*](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm#1009123) available in Sqlplus to make similiar functionality available via regular sql.

I have the objects/function listed below, and it works - except for the `order_param` clause.  It's basically ignored.  I can call the function via:

```
select * from table(describe('my_table',1));
```

or

```
select * from table(describe('my_table',2));
```

**and it results in the same ordering.**

If I replace `order by order_param` with either `order by 1` or `order by 2` in the sql clause in the function, it works as expected.

There must be a better way to get this to work other than to use dynamic sql (or have the function actually choose between 2 sql clauses).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE table_description as object (
  column_name varchar2(30),
  column_id   number, 
  data_type   varchar2(30),
  nullable    varchar2(1)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE table_description_type as table of table_description;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION describe (tname IN VARCHAR2, order_param in NUMBER default 2) RETURN table_description_type AS
-- function to describe a table
-- eg. use via select * from table(describe('table_name'));

  v_ret table_description_type;

BEGIN

 select cast(multiset(
    select column_name, data_type || data_suff "Data Type", nullable from (
      select column_name, column_id, data_type, 
      case when data_type = 'DATE' then '' else '(' ||  
        case when data_type in ('CHAR','VARCHAR2','NCHAR','NVARCHAR') 
        then to_char(char_length) else data_precision || ', ' || data_scale end || ')'
      end data_suff, 
      nullable, data_default, num_nulls, last_analyzed, avg_col_len 
      from all_tab_columns where table_name = upper(tname)
      order by order_param
    )
 ) as table_description_type) into v_ret from dual;

 return v_ret;

END;
/
```

Comment: instead of passing in a NUMBER have you tried passing in the column name as an option?  so select * from table(describe('my_table','data_stuff'));  Or possibly taking off the default?

Comment: @northpole:  Just tried.  Removing `default` clause has no effect, and changing parameter type to VARCHAR2 and passing in the column name gives an ORA-01722: invalid number error.

Comment: just to rule this out, are you passing in the column_name in the function call as a string?  You should not be getting that error.

Comment: @northpole:  yes...exact format as in your 1st comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this the way you're attempting to.  In order for the `order` clause to interpret a numeric value as a column reference, the number has to be there when the query is parsed.  Since you're binding the variable in, it will always interpret your parameter as a value, not a column reference.  To fix this, you'll want to change the `order by` clause logically to select a column based on the value:

```
order by case order_param 
         when 1 then column_name 
         else data_type || data_suff
         end
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.  Makes sense about the numbers needing to be there at parse time.  My function works now